# CSS for my site

Tags: html, css

[image: Site]

In blue there are my div.

I would like with CSS make sure that the space between the div and the image there is and the button over the black top bar but I do not know how to do, any ideas?

My CSS

```
.login_reg{
   float: right;
   color: #e0e0ba;
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
}

.login_reg button{
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: Transparent;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border: none;
    cursor:pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline:none;
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what do you want to do? ... Do you want your Register and Login link on top on the grey area or on the black?

Comment: On top on the grey area

Comment: Can you share the HTML as well..?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/qs91D2bt

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `margin-top` to set how tall the border is and space it out

Answer (score 1):

you can use clear:both to avoid float:right impact for next div

Answer (score 0):

Use margin-top in div having class .login_reg`

```
.login_reg{
   float: right;
   color: #e0e0ba;
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   margine-top: 50px;
}
```